# C++ Win32 application continuously crashes when working with static text control. Can't figure out why

Tags: c++, c, winapi, win32gui

```
SendMessage(hEditControl, WM_GETTEXT,255,(LPARAM)editbuffer);
 GetWindowText(hTextControl, (LPWSTR)allText,GetWindowTextLength(hTextControl));

//allText = appendStrings((char*)TEXT("whatever"), (char*)TEXT("whatever"));
SetWindowText(hTextControl, (LPCWSTR)allText);

//where editbuffer and allText are defined as:

    static WCHAR*       editbuffer;
    static WCHAR*       allText;
```

where hEditControl is the handle to an edit control and hTextControl is a handle to a static text control. I want to take the data from the edit control and append it to the static control text. But my program crashes at the getwindowtext function and I can't figure out why. Even without the appendstring function, it still crashes. By the way, this code is in my message processing function for the main window.

Comment: Have you allocated space for `editBuffer` and `allText`?

Comment: what call would be best to do that

Comment: For `editBuffer` at least, you can just use an array on the stack. If you want to use `GetWindowTextLength`, `allText` will still have to be dynamically allocated with new, or even better, a smart pointer.

Comment: if you put that as an answer ill mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two buffers have no space allocated for them, so anything being written to them is undefined behaviour. You need to allocate memory, preferably static for `editBuffer` and dynamic for `allText`, since C++ doesn't support VLAs.